# what do i need to do to develope an iphone\android app in vs2010?

Tags: c#, iphone, android, xamarin.ios

we are a .net team that devleoped a full app in c# with web services and services that support it. we now want to develope a Mobile app (Android\Iphone) that will look similiar to the original to allow mobile use of it.
we thought about MonoTouch instead of trying to learn Objective-c and to try to develope a cross platform mobile app.
is anyone tried developing a mobile app in vs 2010 in MonoTouch? is there a simple add in for it? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important caveat: **both of these tools are in pain** - since the vendor [fired the dev team](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/May-16.html) (read the "Fighting for Your Right to Party" paragraph). Hopefully soon to be replaced by Xamarin.

MonoDroid does exactly that for android development. For iPhone, you need to be on a mac, and it runs inside MonoDevelop - but ultimately the code is pretty similar.

I would *expect* any Xamarin tools be have similar architecture.

Comment: wow. this is confusing. should i wait for Xamarin to release their product or should i go with no-support\no-development Novell?

Comment: @user437631 - well, that is tricky. They have spoken *very* little, other than to mutter something about completing their roadmap. I'm not hugely convinced, personally.

Comment: As a current MonoTouch subscription holder, we certainly won't be renewing our subscription. I just don't see how Novell can hope to support or develop the MonoTouch product without the product team. Fingers crossed that Xamarin come up with the goods.

Answer (score 1):

There is a GitHub project to allow you to use Visual Studio to code everything except the UI.

https://github.com/follesoe/VSMonoTouch

Also, he has a very good tutorial on doing cross platform mobile dev
https://github.com/follesoe/FlightsNorway/tree/workshop

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MonoTouch roadmap](http://monotouch.net/Roadmap), they plan to make it possible to use MonoTouch in VisualStudio. You still need a mac, though. You can't get around that.

I guess Android would be easier. There is no platform dependency there

Comment: Now if only they had some developers ;p